# Limit the number of characters in the hyperlink field of Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my application, I have a gridview and one of the columns of gridview has a hyperlinkfield in it.
The hyperlink field has a text of few or many words.I want to limit the number of characters displayed in that column.

For example:
if the text insdide the hyperlink says: "Hello all,I have a question for you today"

I want the result on the gridview column to be:"Hello all,I have ..."

and when the user clicks on whole message they will be redirect to a page where whole message is being shown.

My Gridview looks like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="SerialNumber"
                    OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
                    Width="100%"
                    ShowFooter="false"
                    CellPadding="3"
                    CellSpacing="0"
                    EnableViewState="false"
                    AllowPaging="true"
                    PageSize="28"
                    AutoPostBack="true">


                    <Columns>
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="SrNumber" HeaderText="SrNumber" SortExpression="SrNumber" />
                          <asp:BoundField DataField="DateAdded" HeaderText="Created on" SortExpression="DateAdded" />
                          <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="SSrNumber" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="showdetail.aspx?SrNumber={0}" DataTextField="text_Det" HeaderText="text_Det" />
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="DateModified" HeaderText="Last Modified" SortExpression="DateModified" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CreatedBy" HeaderText="CreatedBy" SortExpression="CreatedBy" />


                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

And my Gridview1_RowDataBound looks like:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
          if (e.Row.RowIndex < 0)
            return;

        int _myColumnIndex = 2;   // Substitute your value here

        string text = e.Row.Cells[_myColumnIndex].Text;

        if (text.Length > 10)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[_myColumnIndex].Text = text.Substring(0, 10);
        }
    }
```

The problem is: the code is working properly of all other columns except for the hyperlinkfield.For Hyperlinkfiled it is not taking any data. the string text is comming to be null.Please help!

thank you.

Comment: 'overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; ` style on the gridview column. This way you won't need the rowdatabound at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you are not actually getting access to the hyperlink object itself with the `string text = e.Row.Cells[_myColumnIndex].Text;` syntax.

Try this instead:

```
HyperLink myLink = (HyperLink)e.Row.Cells[2].Controls[0];
string text = myLink.Text;
if (text.Length > 10)
{
    myLink.Text = text.Substring(0, 10);
}
```